# How to convert IST to dd-mm-yyyy fomat

Tags: date, angular6, datefilter, date-pipe

I want date in dd-mmm-yyyy format..I'm getting as  {dayOfYear: 106, dayOfMonth: 16, dayOfWeek: 2, era: 1, year: 2019, …}

I tried datepipe but its throwing error that 'Unable to convert "[object Object]" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'.

```
 item.executionDate=    this.datepipe.transform(item.executionDate , 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: you need to convert your given object into a valid dateformat, after that you can format the date with the date pipe

Comment: whatis the full format of {dayOfYear: 106, dayOfMonth: 16, dayOfWeek: 2, era: 1, year: 2019, …}

Comment: Yes I got the solution .. Now I'm doing it as  let date = (item.executionDate.values[0] + "-" + item.executionDate.values[1] + "-" + item.executionDate.values[2]);

          item.startTime = this.datepipe.transform(new Date(date + " " + item.startTime + " " + "+0000"),"d MMM , y, h:mm:ss a");
          item.endTime = this.datepipe.transform(new Date(date + " " + item.endTime + " " + "+0000"),"d MMM d, y, h:mm:ss a");

Comment: @ysf Do you have any idea how to convert time from 00:00:01 to 8 min 49 second format ???

Comment: you can do it with moment.js https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: @ysf no is ther any way to do in angular

Comment: this problem is not specific to angular and there is no built-in way in angular. you can write your own pipe with custom logic to get such result.